# I am calling EditText in URL is that is right?

Tags: android

I don't think this is a JSON error.

> https://www.xxxxxx.com/TheExample/movielist.php?db=jettysoft&userid=jetty&deliverystatus=2&startdate=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{339a28a
>
> V.ED..CL ........ 0,0-432,136 #7f0900e0
>
> app:id/startdate}&enddate=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{2fcc70fb
>
> V.ED..CL ........ 450,0-882,136 #7f090061 app:id/endDate}

I am trying to get the date in `EditText`.

```
startDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startdate);
endDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.endDate);
doRefresh = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.do_refresh);

startDate.setTag(dp.getStartDate());
endDate.setTag(dp.getEndDate());

startDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new ForCalendar(getContext(), startDate);
        startDate.setText(dp.getStartDate());
    }
});
endDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new ForCalendar(getContext(), endDate);
        endDate.setText(dp.getEndDate());
    }
});
doRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onResume();
    }
});
```

I am calling it in `URL` like this:

```
String server_URL = PathUrls.pathUrl + "evs_getemployeedeliverylist.php?" + "db=" + companyName + "&userid=" + userName + "&deliverystatus=2" + "&startdate=" + startDate + "&enddate=" + endDate;
```

I am getting the above error.

```
public class ForCalendar {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    public ForCalendar(Context ct, final View v) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse((String)v.getTag()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DatePickerDialog dd=new DatePickerDialog(ct, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                EditText ed = (EditText)v;
                ed.setText(year+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+dayOfMonth);
                ed.setText(year+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+dayOfMonth);
            }
        },cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
        dd.show();
    }
}
```

All I am trying to achieve is to get `Date` from what the user selected.

Comment: reformat the first 4-5 rows please, it's a bit confusing

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley do you want me to modify error.

Comment: your quoted first paragraph is unclear (for me).. it's half a link and half text

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, it's wrong. How can you send a View as URL params?

It should be a string.

Instead of sending EditText send the values present in EditText.

`String startDateVal = startDate.getText().toString();`

and send `startDateVal` as params instead of startDate and so the same for endDate as well

Comment: I am getting an empty string.

Comment: `String server_URL = PathUrls.pathUrl + "evs_getemployeedeliverylist.php?" + "db=" + companyName + "&userid=" + userName + "&deliverystatus=2" + "&startdate=" + sDate + "&enddate=" + eDate;` sDate is string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are more, but one problem is surely the way to retrieve the text from your EditText field:

`startDate` in your code is an `EditText` and if you want to retrieve the current text contained in an `EditText` you have to use

`myEditText.getText().toString()`.

The way you are using is trying to pass the EditText itself (which, as string, is the class of the istance, as you can see from the url) instead of the text contained; [here is the official documentation about EditTexts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)